# Parsing pdf files using apache camel

Tags: java, pdf, apache-camel, fileparsing

How do i read/parse pdf files using Apache Camel. Any specific example or code snippets to parse the file ?? 
appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Apache Tika project](http://tika.apache.org/) to extract data from you PDF files. It is a generic tool to extract data from various types of documents. It uses PDFBox under the hood for PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Camel is not about parsing any files at all. You may want to take a look at [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a camel-fop component: http://camel.apache.org/fop but its only for rendering pdf files. There is no support for parsing a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

actually with the component pdf of camel you can actually also extract text, you can see an example of how to do that here: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-pdf/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/pdf/PdfTextExtractionTest.java

the component is based on Apache PDFBox:
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/pdf-component.html